# Remove popover border

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I tried to remove the border from the `UIPopoverController` with by overriding these two methods.  But it did not seem to do anything to the border.

Any suggestions?

```
+ (BOOL)wantsDefaultContentAppearance
{
    NSLog(@"wantsDefaultContentAppearance");
    return NO;
}
+ (UIEdgeInsets)contentViewInsets {
    NSLog(@"contentViewInsets");
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override those methods on the background view class, not the popover controller class.  If you need a starting point for a background view class which mimics the appearance of the system popover, try [C360PopoverBackgroundView](https://github.com/CRedit360/C360PopoverBackgroundView).

Answer (score 2):

You shuld look into `UIPopoverBackgroundView` it allows for you to specify your own popover container (or none at all), here is the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html), also if you search google youll find other examples that might help you.. Once you subclass this you can set the popover to use it by settings its `popoverBackgroundViewClass` property.